# Prove a function to be Lipschitz

Tags: lipschitz-functions

With the condition
$$
0\le f(y)-f(x)-\langle f'(x),y-x\rangle \le \frac{L}{2} \|x-y\|^2,
$$
I want to prove $f'(x)$ is Lipschitz with constant $L$ and is convex.

It is easy to see that $f $ is convex from the first inequality. From the second inequality I derived
$$
\langle f'(y)-f'(x),y-x\rangle \le L \|y-x\|^2
$$
by exchanging the role of $x$ and $y$ and add the two inequalities. However I don't know what to do next. Could anybody tell me?

Thanks.

Comment: @user251257 The original condition is $f(y)-f(x)-\langle f'(x),y-x\rangle \le L/2 \|x-y\|^2$ and I transformed it as the question says...

Comment: I'd suggest that you post the complete question and then add your thoughts and your derivation

Comment: @user190080 I have modified the question. Thanks!

Comment: so $f:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ and is everywhere differentiable?

Comment: Something is wrong here. Counterexample: $f(x)=x^2$. It satisfies the condition (with $L=2$) and is not globally Lipschitz.

Comment: @user190080 Yes.

Comment: @A.G. Sorry. There is a typo. I want to prove $f'(x)$ is Lipschitz.

Comment: ahh...okay...but then you are pretty much done, aren't you? just factor out (your scalarproduct is actually the product) You forgot a $L$ in your second line

Comment: @user190080 Thanks. The final expression should be $\|f'(y)-f'(x)\|\le L \|y-x\|$. I don't know how to derive this.

Comment: I hope I didn't miss anything in the answer, just check and if anything doesn't look convincing at all let me know

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: As it stands, this answer only holds for the 1-dimensional case

so you have

$$
0<\langle f'(y)-f'(x),y-x\rangle \leq L \|y-x\|^2\\
\Leftrightarrow\\
0<[f'(y)-f'(x)](y-x) \leq L \|y-x\|^2
$$
and now you do a case study, case $1):y>x$ and case $2):y<x$.

In case $1)$ we get by dividing $(y-x)$
$$
0<[f'(y)-f'(x)](y-x) \leq L \|y-x\|^2 \\ \Leftrightarrow \\ 
0<[f'(y)-f'(x)] \leq L \|y-x\|
$$
which is the same as in case $2)$ (because $0<[f'(y)-f'(x)](y-x)$), so you are done.

bests

Comment: I think that $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ here with possibly $n\ne 1$.

Comment: @A.G. hmmm,maybe, but I asked the OP in one of the above comments and he said it would be an R to R function

Comment: @user190080 It's on $R^n$. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If the function $f$ is twice differentiable then your condition implies  $\|f''(x)\|\le L$ which easily gives the Lipschitz condition on $f'$. Look, for example, [here, p. 2](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~brecht/eecs227cdocs/Lecture2.pdf).

Otherwise, for a convex differentiable $f$ the following statements are equivalent:

1. $\langle f'(y)-f'(x),y-x\rangle\le L\|y-x\|^2$, $\forall x,y$.
2. $g(x)=\frac{L}{2}\|x\|^2-f(x)$ is convex.
3. $\langle f'(y)-f'(x),y-x\rangle\ge \frac{1}{L}\|f'(y)-f'(x)\|^2$, $\forall x,y$.
4. $\|f'(y)-f'(x)\|\le L\|y-x\|$, $\forall x,y$.

Proof: left as en exercise ;-)